# Recursively find and delete (*.xml / *.txt / *.csv) files older than x days in Linux

Tags: linux, recursion, delete-file

From what I gather through a quick search on the web, you can recursively remove any files folder than x days like this:

```
find /path/to/the/files -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

How do you amend this to only delete `*.xml` / `*.csv` / `*.txt` files (not case sensitive) recursively and leave other files/folders alone.

This is what I came up with and I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about this:

```
find /path/to/the/files -type f \( -name "*.xml" -or -name "*.XML" -or -name "*.csv" -or -name "*.CSV" -or -name "*.txt" -or -name "*.TXT" \) -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: You car replace -name with -iname (case insensetive name), and exec rm {} \ with -delete, but your script is correct.